# How to write a calculation formula with percentage to build a financial calculator in python?

Tags: python

This is a very quick doubt, I'm learning python so I decided to attempt to write a financial simulator just to test out if I can (really simple code with inputs from users and printing of final value), did it a few times with simple formulas and it worked greatly but then I decided to use a formula that needs to calculate a value with percentage and that really got me stuck, here's the formula:

F = P.(1+i)^n + M.[(1+i)^n - 1]/i

Where "i" is the percentage I need to input.

I have tried to insert i normally but it completes messes the calculations up (`x * 6.5` is very different from `x * 6.5%`) and if I try to insert "%" it gives me error messages

This is the code I have so far

```
initial_value = float(input("Initial value: "))
monthly_applications = float(input("Monthly applications: "))
i = float(input("i value in %: "))
time = float(input("Time of investiment in months: "))


total = initial_value * ((1 + i) ^ time) + monthly_applications * ((1 + i) ^ time) - 1) / i

print(total)
```

All I need to figure out is how to insert i in a way that doens't mess with the formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have understood, you have to use i% which will be evaluated as i/100 in the formula. So either you divide I by 100 in the code or enter the I value accordingly. Don't  add % sign.

Comment: I did that and it worked but then I checked in a calculator and the code result is way off, I think the percentage is still not computing exactly as the formula requires

Comment: Make sure to use parantheses correctly. (The code you have entered contains unmatched parantheses). Also ensure that you have correct understand of the formula ,what and how you have to calculate exactly. Double check your calculations and code